# return number of contacts updated in google contacts through api

Tags: php, cakephp, google-api, google-contacts-api

We have written code in `cakephp` to enter contacts in `Google contacts` through `api`,
  Contacts have added in Google through `Google xml` request , but how can we get total number
   of contacts added or updated in Google contacts after code successfully executed

here is code:

```
public function addContact($token=null,$atContacts=null){
foreach ( $atContacts as $contact ) {
$xml = <<<'EOF'
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'               
     xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
     <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'       
     term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
       <title type="text">TITLE</title>
       <gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>First</gd:givenName>
     <gd:additionalName>ADDITIONALNAME</gd:additionalName>
  <gd:familyName>Last</gd:familyName>
 <gd:namePrefix>NAMEPREFIX</gd:namePrefix>
 <gd:nameSuffix>NAMESUFFIX</gd:nameSuffix>
  </gd:name>
 <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work' primary='true'>
<gd:city>CITY</gd:city>
<gd:street>STREET</gd:street>
<gd:region>REGION</gd:region>
<gd:postcode>POSTCODE</gd:postcode>
<gd:country>COUNTRY</gd:country>
</gd:structuredPostalAddress>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home' primary='true'>
 HOMEPHONENUMBER
 </gd:phoneNumber>\
<gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile'>MOBILENO</gd:phoneNumber>
<gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'>WORKPHONENO</gd:phoneNumber>
<gd:email label="home" address="EMAILADDRESS" displayName="DISPLAYNAME" />
</atom:entry>
EOF;


        $xml = str_replace ( "TITLE", $contact->Title, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "EMAILADDRESS", $contact->EMailAddress, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "DISPLAYNAME", $contact->FirstName, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "HOMEPHONENUMBER", $contact->AlternatePhone, 
                    $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "MOBILENO", $contact->MobilePhone, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "WORKPHONENO", $contact->Phone, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "CITY", $contact->City, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "STREET", $contact->AddressLine, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "POSTCODE", $contact->ZipCode, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "REGION", $contact->State, $xml );
        $xml = str_replace ( "COUNTRY", $contact->Country, $xml );
$auth_header = array ('Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8;',
'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . trim ( $token ),
                'Content-length:' . strlen ( $xml ) );
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';
        $curl = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5 );
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml );
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_header );
        $xmlresponse = curl_exec ( $curl );
                }
    return $xmlresponse;
}
```

Comment: Depends how you have written the code thus far. Can we see?

Comment: yes. you can evaluate the code

Answer (score 0):

In your code it does not appear that you do any validation to check that the contact was added successfully and you don't catch any cURL errors either, so with your code as it currently stands just do ..

```
$number_of_contacts = count($atContact);
```

*If taken a guess to the structure of your $atContact array.*

That will give you number of contacts you are trying to add to Google. If you add some validation at some point and want to make that more accurate, then create a new variable...

```
public function addContact($token=null,$atContacts=null){
$number_of_contacts = 0;
foreach ( $atContacts as $contact ) {
   $xml = <<<'EOF'
   ...
   if(no_errors){
       $number_of_contacts++;
   }
```

Comment: we want no of contacts added in google contacts because here in autotask 42 contacts are send but only 39 contacts get added in google