# Address and Name field not working Gmail

Tags: php, xml, api, gmail, google-contacts-api

I am using Advance REST CLIENT for testing and tested that in php code as well.

[here is the link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en#creating_contacts)

I am trying to create contact at Gmail, Everything works fine but the Address is not being inserted and not even the name. Even If I use the same XML as present in the docs

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
    term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
  <gd:name>
     <gd:givenName>Elizabeth</gd:givenName>
     <gd:familyName>Bennet</gd:familyName>
     <gd:fullName>Elizabeth Bennet</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <atom:content type="text">Notes</atom:content>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
    primary="true"
    address="liz@gmail.com" displayName="E. Bennet"/>
  <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
    address="liz@example.org"/>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
    primary="true">
    (206)555-1212
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home">
    (206)555-1213
  </gd:phoneNumber>
  <gd:im address="liz@gmail.com"
    protocol="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#GOOGLE_TALK"
    primary="true"
    rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"/>
  <gd:structuredPostalAddress
      rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work"
      primary="true">
    <gd:city>Mountain View</gd:city>
    <gd:street>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</gd:street>
    <gd:region>CA</gd:region>
    <gd:postcode>94043</gd:postcode>
    <gd:country>United States</gd:country>
    <gd:formattedAddress>
      1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View
    </gd:formattedAddress>
  </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
</atom:entry>
```

it still doesn't add the address and the names, I am afraid if this is something Google is working on ?

I have seen these questions

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761210/google-contacts-api-not-adding-name-and-address-in-google-contact

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761210/google-contacts-api-not-adding-name-and-address-in-google-contact

https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client/issues/153
```

Anyone who can shed light on it, if this is something under development ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Great after struggling with this since 40 hours, I am able to find an answer , you need to specify this in header

```
gdata-version: 3.0
```

Google should update their API details for PHP too.

Hope this helps for future fellows.